# Keynote slide editing, Plus-sign on text box, how to AUTOMATICALLY Resize?, and does it have limits?

Tags: shortcut, font, keynote, text-editor

I already know that, when editing a text box, if a plus sign (+) appears in the bottom center, then it's warning you that there's more text that you're not seeing, that's fine.  And yes, I know how to Cmd-A, resize font, etc.

BUT I also seem to recall that you could somehow magic-click or use a hotkey combination that would tell Keynote to automatically resize the text so that you could see it all.  I can't seem to find that now, but I'm sure I remember it.

I did check and Layout -> Shrink to Fit is already checked/enabled.

Questions:

- Does anybody remember the hotkey or mouse click that would resize the text automatically, so it was all visible?
- Is there maybe some font size limit that the automatic resizing won't go below some value?
- Is there some other easy way to edit the text on the slide?  I usually do want to reduce the amount of text, but for that I need to temporarily see it all.  (beyond Cmd-A functionality)

Other Notes:

- Using the default "white" template
- Keynote version 11.2 on Intel iMac with up-to-date Monterey

Please feel free to make other suggestions.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*"I did check and Layout -> Shrink to Fit is already checked/enabled."*

I wonder if you're perhaps running afoul of the differences in behavior between text boxes and text labels applied to shapes.  You can't actually apply "shrink to fit" to text boxes, but you certainly can to  shapes.  If I paste a blob of text (e.g. "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." as a label to a rectangle w/ "shrink to fit" toggled it'll auto-size down to minuscule when dragging a shape handle as desired.  There does seem to be a min lower bound to keep it readable though.

I can't recall a keyboard combo or similar that does precisely what you're asking for (FWIW, I've been working w/ Keynote on and off since it was Lighthouse Concurrence).

Comment: I was using text boxes, not labels.  So you think that maybe it's a font size limitation, I had wondered that too...